# Publishing page not displayed in navigation

Tags: 2010, navigation, publishing-page

I have created a publishing page. It is published. In my Current navigation I have pages checked. The page however is not being shown. Other pages are. If I create a custom link to the page it is shown. I can't work out why the page is not in the current navigation. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Navigation is security trimmed. Does the page has unique permissions? Also, do you see the page in current navigation settings tree?

Comment: Same perms as other pages. Yes I do see the page in the current navigation settings tree. Just not being rendered in the display.

Comment: On navigation settings, Please Check the max dynamic item limit as well, default is 20. If adding your page exceed the limit, it will not display

Comment: Please could you add this an answer

Comment: Are you creating the publishing pages problematically? whether you UI or code its a manual process. I am assuming you have both publishing and team activated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On navigation settings, Please Check the max dynamic item limit as well, default is 20. If adding your page exceed the limit, it will not display